# MySQL: How to concat names as a tree (Parent-Child categories)

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I'm struggling to get an export from MySQL.

I have two tables (wp_terms and wp_term_taxonomy). In wp_term_taxonomy there is a column "parent" that indicates the parent category of each subcategory. The target is to have a list of all available categories as a tree. Like:

```
Σκύλος
Σκύλος > Τροφές σκύλου
Σκύλος > Τροφές σκύλου > Ξηρά τροφή
Σκύλος > Τροφές σκύλου > Κονσέρβες
Γάτα
Γάτα > Τροφές γάτας
Γάτα > Τροφές γάτας > Ξηρά τροφή
```

and so on...

The parent category has id 0, for example with the data above the IDs are the following:

```
0
0 > 132
0 > 132 > 137
.......
```

I have found in another article the following solution:

```
SELECT T2.term_id
FROM (
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := parent FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = _id) AS parent_id,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := 197, @l := 0) vars,
        wp_term_taxonomy m
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy T2
ON T1._id = T2.term_id
ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC;
```

But 1) it requires to provide the id of the last category and 2) the categories are not concated as a tree.

Any help is much appreciated.

Demo data:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_terms (
  term_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  slug varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  term_group bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (term_id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 415,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 217,
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE wp_term_taxonomy (
  term_taxonomy_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  term_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  taxonomy varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  description longtext NOT NULL,
  parent bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  count bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (term_taxonomy_id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 415,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 178,
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;



INSERT INTO wp_term_taxonomy(term_taxonomy_id, term_id, taxonomy, description, parent, count) VALUES
(15, 15, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(19, 19, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(20, 20, 'product_cat', '', 0, 1),
(21, 21, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(22, 22, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(23, 23, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(52, 52, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(59, 59, 'product_cat', '', 52, 0),
(66, 66, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(67, 67, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(71, 71, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(74, 74, 'product_cat', '', 67, 0),
(88, 88, 'product_cat', '', 71, 0),
(94, 94, 'product_cat', '', 71, 0),
(95, 95, 'product_cat', '', 67, 0),
(96, 96, 'product_cat', '', 71, 0),
(97, 97, 'product_cat', '', 52, 0),
(126, 126, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(127, 127, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(128, 128, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(129, 129, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(130, 130, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(131, 131, 'product_cat', '', 0, 0),
(132, 132, 'product_cat', '', 126, 0),
(133, 133, 'product_cat', '', 126, 0),
(134, 134, 'product_cat', '', 126, 0),
(135, 135, 'product_cat', '', 126, 0),
(136, 136, 'product_cat', '', 126, 0),
(137, 137, 'product_cat', '', 132, 3),
(138, 138, 'product_cat', '', 132, 0),
(139, 139, 'product_cat', '', 132, 0),
(140, 140, 'product_cat', '', 132, 0),
(141, 141, 'product_cat', '', 132, 0),
(142, 142, 'product_cat', '', 132, 0),
(143, 143, 'product_cat', '', 132, 0),
(144, 144, 'product_cat', '', 133, 0),
(145, 145, 'product_cat', '', 133, 0),
(146, 146, 'product_cat', '', 134, 0),
(147, 147, 'product_cat', '', 134, 0),
(148, 148, 'product_cat', '', 134, 0),
(149, 149, 'product_cat', '', 134, 0),
(150, 150, 'product_cat', '', 134, 0),
(151, 151, 'product_cat', '', 134, 0),
(152, 152, 'product_cat', '', 134, 0),
(153, 153, 'product_cat', '', 134, 0),
(154, 154, 'product_cat', '', 135, 0),
(155, 155, 'product_cat', '', 135, 0),
(156, 156, 'product_cat', '', 135, 0),
(157, 157, 'product_cat', '', 135, 0),
(158, 158, 'product_cat', '', 135, 0),
(159, 159, 'product_cat', '', 135, 0),
(160, 160, 'product_cat', '', 135, 0),
(161, 161, 'product_cat', '', 135, 0),
(162, 162, 'product_cat', '', 135, 0),
(163, 163, 'product_cat', '', 135, 0),
(164, 164, 'product_cat', '', 136, 0),
(165, 165, 'product_cat', '', 136, 0),
(166, 166, 'product_cat', '', 136, 0),
(167, 167, 'product_cat', '', 136, 0),
(168, 168, 'product_cat', '', 136, 0),
(169, 169, 'product_cat', '', 136, 0),
(170, 170, 'product_cat', '', 126, 0),
(171, 171, 'product_cat', '', 170, 0),
(172, 172, 'product_cat', '', 170, 0),
(173, 173, 'product_cat', '', 170, 0),
(174, 174, 'product_cat', '', 170, 0),
(175, 175, 'product_cat', '', 170, 0),
(176, 176, 'product_cat', '', 170, 0),
(177, 177, 'product_cat', '', 126, 0),
(178, 178, 'product_cat', '', 177, 0),
(179, 179, 'product_cat', '', 177, 0),
(180, 180, 'product_cat', '', 177, 0),
(181, 181, 'product_cat', '', 177, 0),
(182, 182, 'product_cat', '', 127, 0),
(183, 183, 'product_cat', '', 182, 0),
(184, 184, 'product_cat', '', 182, 0),
(185, 185, 'product_cat', '', 182, 0),
(186, 186, 'product_cat', '', 182, 0),
(187, 187, 'product_cat', '', 182, 0),
(188, 188, 'product_cat', '', 182, 0),
(189, 189, 'product_cat', '', 127, 0),
(190, 190, 'product_cat', '', 189, 0),
(191, 191, 'product_cat', '', 189, 0),
(192, 192, 'product_cat', '', 189, 0),
(193, 193, 'product_cat', '', 127, 0),
(194, 194, 'product_cat', '', 193, 0),
(195, 195, 'product_cat', '', 193, 0),
(196, 196, 'product_cat', '', 193, 0),
(197, 197, 'product_cat', '', 193, 0),
(198, 198, 'product_cat', '', 193, 0),
(199, 199, 'product_cat', '', 193, 0),
(200, 200, 'product_cat', '', 127, 0),
(201, 201, 'product_cat', '', 200, 0),
(202, 202, 'product_cat', '', 200, 0),
(203, 203, 'product_cat', '', 200, 0),
(204, 204, 'product_cat', '', 200, 0),
(205, 205, 'product_cat', '', 200, 0),
(206, 206, 'product_cat', '', 127, 0),
(207, 207, 'product_cat', '', 206, 0),
(208, 208, 'product_cat', '', 206, 0),
(209, 209, 'product_cat', '', 206, 0),
(210, 210, 'product_cat', '', 206, 0),
(211, 211, 'product_cat', '', 206, 0),
(212, 212, 'product_cat', '', 206, 0),
(213, 213, 'product_cat', '', 206, 0),
(214, 214, 'product_cat', '', 127, 0),
(215, 215, 'product_cat', '', 214, 0),
(216, 216, 'product_cat', '', 214, 0),
(217, 217, 'product_cat', '', 214, 0),
(218, 218, 'product_cat', '', 214, 0),
(219, 219, 'product_cat', '', 214, 0),
(220, 220, 'product_cat', '', 127, 0),
(221, 221, 'product_cat', '', 220, 0),
(222, 222, 'product_cat', '', 220, 0),
(223, 223, 'product_cat', '', 220, 0),
(224, 224, 'product_cat', '', 220, 0),
(225, 225, 'product_cat', '', 220, 0),
(226, 226, 'product_cat', '', 128, 0),
(227, 227, 'product_cat', '', 226, 0),
(228, 228, 'product_cat', '', 226, 0),
(229, 229, 'product_cat', '', 226, 0),
(230, 230, 'product_cat', '', 128, 0),
(231, 231, 'product_cat', '', 230, 0),
(232, 232, 'product_cat', '', 230, 0),
(233, 233, 'product_cat', '', 230, 0),
(234, 234, 'product_cat', '', 230, 0),
(235, 235, 'product_cat', '', 230, 0),
(236, 236, 'product_cat', '', 230, 0),
(237, 237, 'product_cat', '', 230, 0),
(238, 238, 'product_cat', '', 128, 0),
(239, 239, 'product_cat', '', 238, 0),
(240, 240, 'product_cat', '', 238, 0),
(241, 241, 'product_cat', '', 238, 0),
(242, 242, 'product_cat', '', 238, 0),
(243, 243, 'product_cat', '', 238, 0),
(244, 244, 'product_cat', '', 128, 0),
(245, 245, 'product_cat', '', 244, 0),
(246, 246, 'product_cat', '', 129, 0),
(247, 247, 'product_cat', '', 246, 0),
(248, 248, 'product_cat', '', 246, 0),
(249, 249, 'product_cat', '', 246, 0),
(250, 250, 'product_cat', '', 129, 0),
(251, 251, 'product_cat', '', 250, 0),
(252, 252, 'product_cat', '', 250, 0),
(253, 253, 'product_cat', '', 254, 0),
(254, 254, 'product_cat', '', 129, 0),
(255, 255, 'product_cat', '', 254, 0),
(256, 256, 'product_cat', '', 254, 0),
(257, 257, 'product_cat', '', 254, 0),
(258, 258, 'product_cat', '', 254, 0),
(259, 259, 'product_cat', '', 254, 0),
(260, 260, 'product_cat', '', 254, 0),
(261, 261, 'product_cat', '', 129, 0),
(262, 262, 'product_cat', '', 261, 0),
(263, 263, 'product_cat', '', 261, 0),
(264, 264, 'product_cat', '', 261, 0),
(265, 265, 'product_cat', '', 130, 0),
(266, 266, 'product_cat', '', 265, 0),
(267, 267, 'product_cat', '', 130, 0),
(268, 268, 'product_cat', '', 267, 0),
(269, 269, 'product_cat', '', 267, 0),
(270, 270, 'product_cat', '', 267, 0),
(271, 271, 'product_cat', '', 267, 0),
(272, 272, 'product_cat', '', 130, 0),
(273, 273, 'product_cat', '', 272, 0),
(274, 274, 'product_cat', '', 272, 0),
(275, 275, 'product_cat', '', 272, 0),
(276, 276, 'product_cat', '', 131, 0),
(277, 277, 'product_cat', '', 276, 0),
(278, 278, 'product_cat', '', 276, 0),
(279, 279, 'product_cat', '', 276, 0),
(280, 280, 'product_cat', '', 131, 0),
(281, 281, 'product_cat', '', 280, 0),
(282, 282, 'product_cat', '', 280, 0),
(283, 283, 'product_cat', '', 280, 0),
(284, 284, 'product_cat', '', 280, 0),
(285, 285, 'product_cat', '', 280, 0),
(286, 286, 'product_cat', '', 280, 0),
(287, 287, 'product_cat', '', 280, 0),
(288, 288, 'product_cat', '', 280, 0),
(289, 289, 'product_cat', '', 280, 0),
(290, 290, 'product_cat', '', 131, 0),
(291, 291, 'product_cat', '', 290, 0),
(292, 292, 'product_cat', '', 290, 0),
(293, 293, 'product_cat', '', 290, 0),
(294, 294, 'product_cat', '', 290, 0),
(295, 295, 'product_cat', '', 290, 0),
(296, 296, 'product_cat', '', 290, 0);

INSERT INTO wp_terms(term_id, name) VALUES
(1, 'Uncategorized'),
(2, 'simple'),
(3, 'grouped'),
(4, 'variable'),
(5, 'external'),
(6, 'exclude-from-search'),
(7, 'exclude-from-catalog'),
(8, 'featured'),
(9, 'outofstock'),
(10, 'rated-1'),
(11, 'rated-2'),
(12, 'rated-3'),
(13, 'rated-4'),
(14, 'rated-5'),
(15, 'Uncategorized'),
(16, 'FRESH VEGETABLES'),
(17, 'ARTICLES'),
(18, 'CHAT'),
(19, 'Breakfast'),
(20, 'Cooking'),
(21, 'Frozen'),
(22, 'Fruits'),
(23, 'Vegetables'),
(36, 'Accessories'),
(37, 'All about clothing'),
(38, 'Articles'),
(39, 'Asides'),
(40, 'Bag'),
(41, 'Fashion'),
(42, 'Fashion trends'),
(43, 'Haircuts &amp; hairstyles'),
(44, 'Make-up &amp; beauty'),
(45, 'Model'),
(46, 'Traveling'),
(47, 'Bags'),
(48, 'Dresses'),
(49, 'Fashion'),
(50, 'Shoes'),
(51, 'Skirts'),
(52, 'Accessories'),
(54, 'Bag'),
(56, 'Blouse'),
(59, 'Caps'),
(60, 'CEO'),
(61, 'Clothes'),
(62, 'Design'),
(63, 'Design'),
(64, 'Developer'),
(65, 'Dress'),
(66, 'Dress'),
(67, 'Electronics'),
(70, 'Fashion'),
(71, 'Fashion'),
(72, 'glasses'),
(74, 'Headphone'),
(75, 'Hub'),
(77, 'Jacket'),
(78, 'Jeans'),
(81, 'man'),
(82, 'Marketing'),
(84, 'Onepiece'),
(85, 'Polo'),
(87, 'Shirt'),
(88, 'Shoes'),
(89, 'Skirt'),
(91, 'Sports'),
(92, 'Sweater'),
(93, 'T-shirt'),
(94, 'T-Shirts'),
(95, 'Toys'),
(96, 'Trousers'),
(97, 'Watches'),
(98, 'Women'),
(101, 'My Account'),
(103, 'Aside'),
(104, 'Image'),
(105, 'Video'),
(124, 'Main Menu'),
(125, 'Secondary Menu'),
(126, 'Σκύλος'),
(127, 'Γάτα'),
(128, 'Τρωκτικό'),
(129, 'Πτηνό'),
(130, 'Ερπετό'),
(131, 'Ψάρι'),
(132, 'Τροφές Σκύλου'),
(133, 'Κλινικές Τροφές Σκύλου'),
(134, 'Μεταφορά - Διαμονή'),
(135, 'Αξεσουάρ'),
(136, 'Υγιεινή'),
(137, 'Ξηρά Τροφή'),
(138, 'Κονσέρβες'),
(139, 'Φακελάκια'),
(140, 'Κεσεδάκια'),
(141, 'Λιχουδιές'),
(142, 'Κόκκαλα'),
(143, 'Γάλατα-Μπιμπερό'),
(144, 'Ξηρά Τροφή'),
(145, 'Κονσέρβες'),
(146, 'Τσάντες μεταφοράς'),
(147, 'Κλουβιά μεταφοράς-Ανταλλακτικά'),
(148, 'Αξεσουάρ αυτοκινήτου'),
(149, 'Πινακίδες Προειδοποίησης'),
(150, 'Κρεβάτια-Στρώματα'),
(151, 'Πατάκια-Κουβέρτες'),
(152, 'Σπίτια-Πόρτες'),
(153, 'Πάρκα-Κλουβιά Εκθέσεως'),
(154, 'Μπολ-Ταΐστρες-Ποτίστρες-Σουπλά-Δοχεία Αποθήκευσης'),
(155, 'Περιλαίμια-Σαμαράκια'),
(156, 'Οδηγοί'),
(157, 'Πτυσσόμενοι οδηγοί'),
(158, 'Αλυσίδες-Φίμωτρα'),
(159, 'Παιχνίδια'),
(160, 'Ρούχα-Παπούτσια-Εποχιακά Είδη'),
(161, 'Κοκαλάκια-Φουλάρια-Γυαλιά Ηλίου'),
(162, 'Ταυτότητες-Κουδουνάκια'),
(163, 'Εκπαίδευση'),
(164, 'Πάνες &amp; Βρακάκια'),
(165, 'Στοματική φροντίδα'),
(166, 'Σακούλες περισυλλογής απορριμάτων'),
(167, 'Μαντηλάκια καθαρισμού'),
(168, 'Προστατευτικά-Καθαριστικά χώρου'),
(169, 'Επιδαπέδιες Πάνες'),
(170, 'Καλλωπισμός'),
(171, 'Σαμπουάν-Αφροί Καθαρισμού'),
(172, 'Βούρτσες-Χτένες'),
(173, 'Νυχοκόπτες'),
(174, 'Αρώματα'),
(175, 'Περιποίηση'),
(176, 'Κουρευτικές μηχανές'),
(177, 'Υγεία'),
(178, 'Αντιπαρασιτικά'),
(179, 'Βιταμίνες-Συμπληρώματα διατροφής'),
(180, 'Ελισαβετιανά Κολάρα'),
(181, 'Προβλήματα συμπεριφοράς'),
(182, 'Τροφές Γάτας'),
(183, 'Ξηρά Τροφή'),
(184, 'Κονσέρβες'),
(185, 'Φακελάκια'),
(186, 'Κεσεδάκια'),
(187, 'Λιχουδιές'),
(188, 'Γάλατα-Μπιμπερό'),
(189, 'Κλινικές Τροφές Γάτας'),
(190, 'Ξηρά Τροφή'),
(191, 'Κονσέρβες'),
(192, 'Φακελάκια'),
(193, 'Μεταφορά-Διαμονή'),
(194, 'Τσάντες μεταφοράς'),
(195, 'Κλουβιά μεταφοράς'),
(196, 'Κρεβάτια-Στρώματα'),
(197, 'Πατάκια-Κουβέρτες'),
(198, 'Πόρτες-Ασφάλεια'),
(199, 'Αξεσουάρ'),
(200, 'Αξεσουάρ'),
(201, 'Μπολ-Ταΐστρες-Ποτίστρες-Σουπλά'),
(202, 'Περιλαίμια-Σαμαράκια'),
(203, 'Παιχνίδια'),
(204, 'Ονυχοδρόμια'),
(205, 'Ταυτότητες-Κουδουνάκια'),
(206, 'Υγιεινή'),
(207, 'Άμμοι'),
(208, 'Τουαλέτες'),
(209, 'Φτυάρια'),
(210, 'Αρωματικά Άμμου'),
(211, 'Προστατευτικά χώρου-Καθαριστικά'),
(212, 'Μαντηλάκια καθαρισμού'),
(213, 'Σακούλες υγιεινής-Φίλτρα'),
(214, 'Καλλωπισμός'),
(215, 'Βούρτσες-Χτένες'),
(216, 'Νυχοκόπτες'),
(217, 'Αρώματα'),
(218, 'Αφροί Καθαρισμού'),
(219, 'Περιποίηση'),
(220, 'Υγεία'),
(221, 'Βιταμίνες - Συμπληρώματα'),
(222, 'Φαρμακευτικά προϊόντα'),
(223, 'Catnip-Γρασίδι'),
(224, 'Αντιπαρασιτικά'),
(225, 'Προβλήματα συμπεριφοράς'),
(226, 'Τροφές'),
(227, 'Κύρια Τροφή'),
(228, 'Λιχουδιές'),
(229, 'Χόρτα'),
(230, 'Αξεσουάρ'),
(231, 'Κλουβιά'),
(232, 'Κλουβιά Μεταφοράς'),
(233, 'Ταΐστρες-Σουπλά'),
(234, 'Ποτίστρες'),
(235, 'Παιχνίδια'),
(236, 'Σαμαράκια'),
(237, 'Εσωτερική Διακόσμηση'),
(238, 'Υγιεινή'),
(239, 'Άμμοι'),
(240, 'Υποστρώματα'),
(241, 'Είδη Καθαρισμού Ζώου'),
(242, 'Νυχοκόπτες-Βούρτσες'),
(243, 'Τουαλέτες'),
(244, 'Υγεία'),
(245, 'Συμπληρώματα Διατροφής'),
(246, 'Τροφές'),
(247, 'Κύρια Τροφή'),
(248, 'Λιχουδιές'),
(249, 'Βιταμίνες'),
(250, 'Υγεία'),
(251, 'Συμπληρώματα Διατροφής'),
(252, 'Αξεσουάρ'),
(253, 'Κλουβιά &amp; Ορθοστάτες'),
(254, 'Αξεσουάρ'),
(255, 'Ταΐστρες &amp; Αυγοθήκες'),
(256, 'Ποτίστρες'),
(257, 'Παιχνίδια'),
(258, 'Φωλιές'),
(259, 'Κλαδιά'),
(260, 'Μπανιέρες'),
(261, 'Υγιεινή'),
(262, 'Άμμοι'),
(263, 'Υποστρώματα'),
(264, 'Νυχοκόπτες'),
(265, 'Τροφές'),
(266, 'Κύρια Τροφή'),
(267, 'Αξεσουάρ'),
(268, 'Ερπετάρια'),
(269, 'Χελωνιέρες'),
(270, 'Φωτισμός-Θερμότητα'),
(271, 'Θερμόμετρα &amp; Υδρόμετρα'),
(272, 'Υγιεινή &amp; Υγεία'),
(273, 'Φάρμακα'),
(274, 'Συμπληρώματα'),
(275, 'Υποστρώματα'),
(276, 'Τροφές'),
(277, 'Τροπικά Ψάρια'),
(278, 'Θαλασσινά Ψάρια'),
(279, 'Χρυσόψαρα-Κοϊ'),
(280, 'Αξεσουάρ'),
(281, 'Ενυδρεία-Βάσεις Ενυδρείων'),
(282, 'Αντλίες Αέρα'),
(283, 'Φίλτρα-Υλικά Φιλτραρίσματος'),
(284, 'Φωτισμός-Θερμότητα'),
(285, 'Αντλίες Νερού-Κυκλοφορητές'),
(286, 'Διακοσμητικά'),
(287, 'Διακοσμητικά Χαλίκια-Βότσαλα'),
(288, 'Απόχες'),
(289, 'Γενικός Εξοπλισμός'),
(290, 'Φροντίδα-Υγιεινή'),
(291, 'Φάρμακα'),
(292, 'Βελτιώσεις Νερού Ενυδρείων'),
(293, 'Βελτιώσεις Νερού Λιμνών'),
(294, 'Λιπασματα-Υποστρώμματα'),
(295, 'Είδη Καθαρισμού'),
(296, 'Σετ Τεστ'),
(297, 'Άμεση παραλαβή / Παράδοση 1 εώς 3 μέρες'),
(298, 'Παράδοση 4 - 10 μέρες'),
(299, 'Εξαντλημένο / Αναμονή παραλαβής απο προμηθευτή'),
(300, 'Brekkies'),
(301, 'Canis'),
(302, 'Christopherus'),
(303, 'Duck Dog'),
(304, 'Forma 360'),
(305, 'Friskies'),
(306, 'Frolic'),
(307, 'Gusto'),
(308, 'Hills'),
(309, 'Kippy'),
(310, 'Mediterranean'),
(311, 'Pedigree'),
(312, 'Planet Pet'),
(313, 'Proplan'),
(314, 'Purina Dog Chow'),
(315, 'Quattro'),
(316, 'Royal Canin'),
(317, 'Simpaty'),
(318, '300 g'),
(319, '500 g'),
(320, '700 g'),
(321, '800 g'),
(322, '1 kg'),
(323, '1.4 kg'),
(324, '1.5 kg'),
(325, '2 kg'),
(326, '2.2 kg'),
(327, '2.5kg'),
(328, '3 kg'),
(329, '3.5 kg'),
(330, '4 kg'),
(331, '6 kg'),
(332, '7 kg'),
(333, '8 kg'),
(334, '9 kg'),
(335, '10 kg'),
(336, '11 kg'),
(337, '11+3 kg'),
(338, '11.5+3 kg'),
(339, '12 kg'),
(340, '14 kg'),
(341, '14.5 kg'),
(342, '15 kg'),
(343, '18 kg'),
(344, '20 kg'),
(345, 'Αρνί'),
(346, 'Βοδινό'),
(347, 'Γαλοπούλα'),
(348, 'Ελάφι'),
(349, 'Κοτόπουλο'),
(350, 'Λαχανικά'),
(351, 'Μοσχάρι'),
(352, 'Πάπια'),
(353, 'Πουλερικά'),
(354, 'Σολομό'),
(355, 'Τόνος'),
(356, 'Χοιρινό'),
(357, 'Ψάρι'),
(358, 'Adult'),
(359, 'Junior'),
(360, 'Puppy'),
(361, 'Mature'),
(362, 'Senior'),
(363, 'Mature/Senior'),
(364, 'Mother/Baby dog'),
(365, 'Beagle'),
(366, 'Bichon Frise'),
(367, 'Boxer'),
(368, 'Caniche Poodle'),
(369, 'Cavalier King Charles Spaniel'),
(370, 'Chihuahua'),
(371, 'Cocker Spaniel'),
(372, 'Dachshund'),
(373, 'Dalmatian'),
(374, 'Bulldog'),
(375, 'French Bulldog'),
(376, 'German Shepherd'),
(377, 'Golden Retriever'),
(378, 'Setter'),
(379, 'Jack Russell Terrier'),
(380, 'Labrador Retriever'),
(381, 'Maltese'),
(382, 'Miniature Schnauzer'),
(383, 'Pug'),
(384, 'Rottweiler'),
(385, 'Shih Tzu'),
(386, 'West Highland'),
(387, 'Yorkshire Terrier'),
(388, 'All Sizes'),
(389, 'X-Small'),
(390, 'Small'),
(391, 'Medium'),
(392, 'Large'),
(393, 'Giant'),
(394, 'Active'),
(395, 'Dental'),
(396, 'Digestive Care'),
(397, 'Exigent'),
(398, 'Indoor'),
(399, 'Light'),
(400, 'Mother/ Babydog'),
(401, 'Relax'),
(402, 'Sensitive'),
(403, 'Sterilised'),
(404, 'Skin And Stomach'),
(405, 'Urinary'),
(406, 'Weight Control'),
(407, 'Ναι'),
(408, 'Όχι'),
(409, 'Όλες'),
(410, 'Όλες'),
(411, 'Όλες'),
(412, 'Όλα τα μεγέθη'),
(413, 'Χωρίς ειδική ανάγκη');
```

Comment: with mysql 8 and recursive cte this is quite easy to do, bust as tree hirachs are not nartive to a rdms you must to the recursive part in a function

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is not the perfect solution but I managed to get the requested results. I post it in case someone else needs this answer:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
IFNULL(wt6.name,''), 
        CASE 
            WHEN wt6.name IS NULL
            THEN ''
            ELSE ' > '
        END,
IFNULL(wt5.name,''), 
        CASE 
            WHEN wt5.name IS NULL
            THEN ''
            ELSE ' > '
        END,
IFNULL(wt4.name,''), 
        CASE 
            WHEN wt4.name IS NULL
            THEN ''
            ELSE ' > '
        END,
IFNULL(wt3.name,''), 
        CASE 
            WHEN wt3.name IS NULL
            THEN ''
            ELSE ' > '
        END,
IFNULL(wt2.name,''), 
        CASE 
            WHEN wt2.name IS NULL
            THEN ''
            ELSE ' > '
        END,
IFNULL(wt1.name,'')
) AS Categories
FROM wp_term_taxonomy p1
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy p2 on p2.term_id = p1.parent 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy p3 on p3.term_id = p2.parent 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy p4 on p4.term_id = p3.parent  
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy p5 on p5.term_id = p4.parent  
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy p6 on p6.term_id = p5.parent
LEFT JOIN wp_terms wt1 ON p1.term_id = wt1.term_id
left JOIN wp_terms wt2 ON p2.term_id = wt2.term_id
left JOIN wp_terms wt3 ON p3.term_id = wt3.term_id
left JOIN wp_terms wt4 ON p4.term_id = wt4.term_id
left JOIN wp_terms wt5 ON p5.term_id = wt5.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms wt6 ON p6.term_id = wt6.term_id
WHERE p1.taxonomy='product_cat'
ORDER BY 1;
```